# Merged arrays are not in correct array format

Tags: php, arrays

I' am currently stuck in a issue where merged array only showing first array on dump. Attached is the image of the dump.

[image: Array Dump]

As you can see the first (index 0) array comes out really well, but the second and third array are not in correct array format.

**This function appends array to $add_admin_menu variable**

```
$add_admin_menu = array();
  function add_admin_menu( $args ) {
    global $add_admin_menu;
    if( !empty($add_admin_menu) ){
      $arg1 = $add_admin_menu;
      return $add_admin_menu = array_merge($arg1, $args);
    } else {
      return $add_admin_menu = array($args);
    }
}
```

**This function just calls the variable $add_admin_menu and makes it into a function**

```
function get_admin_menu(){
  global $add_admin_menu;
  return $add_admin_menu;
}
```

**This is how I call the function add_admin_menu and pack array inside it **

```
$args1 = array("Dashboard", "dashboard.php", "dashboard");
add_admin_menu($args1); 

$args2 = array("Posts", "posts.php", "posts");
add_admin_menu($args2); 

$args3 = array("Pages", "pages.php", "pages");
add_admin_menu($args3);

$get_admin_menu = get_admin_menu();
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $get_admin_menu );
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Why -1, whats wrong with the question?

Comment: What happens if you do: `if( !empty($add_admin_menu) ){ $arg1 = $add_admin_menu; array_push($add_admin_menu, $args); }`

Comment: @Darren :: I' am getting the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change this:

```
return $add_admin_menu = array_merge($arg1, $args);
```

to this:

```
return $add_admin_menu[] = $args;
```